# One To Many Relationships field always null

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi Everyone When I was trying to use Model.SubCategories but it is always null. I Don't understand anything.

MyModel like this:

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int SubCategoryID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

}
```

DBContext Like This:

```
public class EntitiesContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

My Action Like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(database.Categories.ToList());
    }
```

My Views snippet Like This:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.SubCategories) //always null
   {
      //...
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to declare SubCategory property as `ICollection` instead of `IEnumerable`.

Comment: does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'" exception throwing :(

Comment: My mistake. I actually did not looked carefully your code. Did you initialize the property SubCategories before you want to use is?

Comment: A lot of Thanks :) IEnumerable<Category> categories = database.Categories.ToList();
foreach (var item in categories)item.SubCategories = database.SubCategories.Where(t => t.CategoryID == item.CategoryID).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

`SubCategories` are `virtual`, which means lazy loading. That means, the table will not be retrieved, unless you request it. Use `Include` method.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(database.Categories.Include("SubCategory").ToList());
}
```

Comment: Thaks for your answer but it's throw an exception: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType Sample.Models.Category does not declare a navigation property with the name 'SubCategory'.